# Virtual Server with no Snappoint function: How do I make a full-backup of the running system?

Tags: server, virtualbox, ssh, backup, sftp

So I'm currently experimenting with a couple of uni servers. All of them have no option of creating snappoints in the vSphere Client. So I'm left to search for a backup solution in case the experimenting makes everything kaput.

Seeing as that I'm a linux beginner, what options are there for me to make a full backup of the currently running Ubuntu 16.04 for emergency cases when everything goes kaput.

To clarify: I have ssh access, I have a terminal access with putty. I can log with Filezilla via sftp and see all the folders. I have root access.

```
root@xxx:~# df -h
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                 3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                797M   18M  780M   3% /run
/dev/mapper/vcac--ubuntu16--vg-root   15G  1.9G   12G  14% /
tmpfs                                3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                            472M   58M  391M  13% /boot
/dev/mapper/data-disc1                50G   33M   50G   1% /net/xxx/disc1
tmpfs                                797M     0  797M   0% /run/user/0
```

To clarifiy, I want to do a backup of this output. Obviously not What's been mapped, but what is used.

Comment: First of all snapshots should not be used for backup, as they add some significant overhead over time, when a lot of changes have occured. Rather you should in some way make a export of the VM image from the hypervisor, either manually, or using a backup framework such as Veeam (free for homelab use). But this is not really a Ubuntu question, but rather a question for your hypervisor. I'd suggest asking it at [Serverault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: Again, no. Only way for me to make ANY backups is either SSH or SFTP. Anything else no can do. But I'll try Serverault.

Comment: You can always do a image from within the instance, but if everything goes kaputski you have the problem of how to restore it. With VM's the answer is that you either make backups of configuration files that you've changed to allow easy manual recovery, or you take a VM level backup so that you simply can replace the VM in question when you need. There's no middle ground IMHO...

Comment: Let's assume it never goes full kaputski, but with expirementing with sudo apt-get and changing config files and installing and uninstalling after all that I want to go back how it was at the beginning, having STILL access to ssh and sftp. What do I do? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

### Make a backup of configuration files

You will probably be interested in keeping a backup of your configuration files. These typically live in `/etc`. Make a tar of `/etc`, which you can poke trough when you need it:

```
ssh user@hostname "sudo tar cvj /etc/" > etcbackup.tar.bz2
```

Note that you should not restore all of it; you should restore the configuration files you have messed up.

### Get list of installed packages

```
dpkg --get-selections > packagelist.txt
```

This will create packagelist.txt with all currently installed packages. You can read this to look for specific packages, or you can install according to this list automatically

```
dpkg --set-selections < packagelist.txt
apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
```

### Additional apps

If you use for instance MariaDB you probably want to back up your databases. This can be done with the `mysqldump` utility. Similar tools exists for other databases.

If you do web development, look into housing the project in for instance git, so that you don't work live on the remote system, but have a version control system.

Tho, I'd not bother with backing up anything but the user data on a system. Configuration settings should be documented, but fairly easy to restore from documentation. List of installed packages probably follows somewhat from requirements for the applications hosted.

Comment: Thank you, that's a start. But can't I just make a whole tarball or something from the df -h I posted above. Why, who, what's not importat. Is it possible to make and restore that way?

Comment: You could make a tar ball of the whole system, but you would basically have no way of restoring it, and expecting it to work.